# How do you affect line spacing in JavaFX hyperlinks?

Tags: css, hyperlink, javafx, spacing

I have a vbox, where I'm putting some hyperlinks.

```
Hyperlink clickableString;
clickableString = new Hyperlink();
clickableString.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;-fx-padding: 0; -fx-line-spacing: 0em;");  //set the hyperlink to black.
clickableString.setLineSpacing(0);      
clickableString.setText("This is a test");
myVBox.getChildren().add(clickableString);  

clickableString = new Hyperlink();
clickableString.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;-fx-padding: 0; -fx-line-spacing: 0em;");  //set the hyperlink to black.
clickableString.setLineSpacing(0);      
clickableString.setText("This is a test");
myVBox.getChildren().add(clickableString);
```

I'm trying to get the spacing between the characters as small as possible, so that I can fit as many rows as possible.  As it is, the space between the lines is about half a character tall.  Does anyone know how to fine tune this?

Is it possible that the font itself is taking up the white space, and therefore, I can't remove the white space?  Or is there some kind of padding that I can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Men,

I was looking into the same thing, but "-fx-line-spacing" does not appear in the official JavaFX CSS documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

- Edit -

But testing it worked. In my case I had to put a negative number to get the lines closer to each other.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: No, I'm answering.